# Ideablade DevForce ORM 3.8.13 is not compatible with Devexpress 18.1.13

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, devforce

we are struggling with the Bug "XtraReports v18.1.3: problems with new FilterString Editor". I saw that the problem was solved with the Devexpress Version 18.1.13. We are currently using Devexpress winform-controls version 18.1.3 together with the Ideablade DevForce ORM 3.8.13. Therefore we are not able to upgrade to a version beyond 18.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AssemblyBindingRedirector which ships with DevForce to set up binding redirects to allow DevForce to work with the maintenance releases of DevExpress.